# Interrupt a long running Jersey Client operation

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, httpconnection, cancellation

I am using the Oracle Jersey `Client`, and am trying to cancel a long running `get` or `put` operation.

### The `Client` is constructed as:

```
JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(new ObjectMapper());
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getSingletons().add(provider);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

### The following code is executed on a worker thread:

```
File bigZipFile = new File("/home/me/everything.zip");

WebResource resource = client.resource("https://putfileshere.com");
Builder builder = resource.getRequestBuilder();

builder.type("application/zip").put(bigZipFile); //This will take a while!
```

I want to cancel this long-running `put`. When I try to interrupt the worker thread, the `put` operation continues to run. From what I can see, the Jersey Client makes no attempt to check for `Thread.interrupted()`.

I see the same behavior when using an `AsyncWebResource` instead of `WebResource` and using `Future.cancel(true)` on the `Builder.put(..)` call.

So far, the only solution I have come up with to interrupt this is throwing a `RuntimeException` in a [ContainerListener](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/using_containerlistener):

```
client.addFilter(new ConnectionListenerFilter(
  new OnStartConnectionListener(){
    public ContainerListener onStart(ClientRequest cr) {
      return new ContainerListener(){
        public void onSent(long delta, long bytes) {

          //If the thread has been interrupted, stop the operation
          if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Upload or Download canceled");
          }

          //Report progress otherwise

        }
      }...
```

I am wondering if there is a better solution (perhaps when creating the `Client`) that correctly handles interruptible I/O without using a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Is it the upload of the data that takes that long or its processing on the server?

Comment: @isnot2bad It is the upload of the data. Let's say a 20MB file, on a slow connection, could take quite some time to upload.

Comment: Same problem here, in 2015 I keep wondering why do people create libs with no clear cancelling mechanism. I think I will go with Apache Http client.

Comment: Now I wonder if the Apache HTTP client listens for interruptions...

Comment: Looks like Java v16 introduced cancelable futures which might help if you're okay with cancelling the specific HTTP request thread.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252515

Comment: Also looks like OkHTTP has added support for listening for thread interruptions:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6611

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there is a better solution (perhaps when creating the Client) that correctly handles interruptible I/O without using a RuntimeException.

Yeah, interrupting the thread will only work if the code is watching for the interrupts or calling other methods (such as `Thread.sleep(...)`) that watch for it.

Throwing an exception out of listener doesn't sound like a bad idea.  I would certainly create your own `RuntimeException` class such as `TimeoutRuntimeException` or something so you can specifically catch and handle it.

Another thing to do would be to close the underlying IO stream that is being written to which would cause an `IOException` but I'm not familiar with Jersey so I'm not sure if you can get access to the connection.

Ah, here's an idea.  Instead of putting the `File`, how about putting some sort of extension on a `BufferedInputStream` that is reading from the `File` but also has a timeout.  So Jersey would be reading from the buffer and at some point it would throw an `IOException` if the timeout expires.

Comment: Thanks for the response! At some point I ended up writing an `InterruptableInputStream`; a class that extends `InputStream`. It checks for `currentThread` interruption on an override of each `InputStream` method, throwing an IOException if the thread is interrupted. Both solutions seem to work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jersey 2.35, the above API has changed. A timeout has been introduces in the client builder which can set read timeout. If the server takes too long to respond, the underlying socket will timeout. However, if the server starts sending the response, it shall not timeout. This can be utilized, ***if*** the server does not start sending partial response, which depends on the server implementation.

```
            client=(JerseyClient)JerseyClientBuilder
                                .newBuilder()
                                .connectTimeout(1*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .readTimeout(5*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()
```

The current filters and interceptors are for data only and the solution posted in the original question will not work with filters and interceptors (*though I admit I may have missed something there*).

Another way is to get hold of the underlying HttpUrlConnection (for standard Jersey client configuration) and it seems to be possible with org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnectorProvider

```
        HttpUrlConnectorProvider httpConProvider=new HttpUrlConnectorProvider();
        httpConProvider.connectionFactory(new CustomHttpUrlConnectionfactory());

public static class CustomHttpUrlConnectionfactory implements 
HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory{

    @Override
    public HttpURLConnection getConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("CustomHttpUrlConnectionfactory ..... called");
        
        return (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        
    }//getConnection closing

}//inner-class closing
```

I did try the connection provider approach, however, I could not get that working. The idea would be to keep reference to the connection by some means (thread id etc.) and close it if the communication is taking too long. The primary problem was I could not find a way to register the provider with the client. The standard

```
.register(httpConProvider)
```

mechanism does not seem to work (or perhaps it is not supposed to work like that) and the documentation is a bit sketchy in that direction.

Comment: suggested approach seems like an overkill to me, but I see the potential if Jersey is the only way to go